# Force close error in Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting a force close error when i start application in emulator through eclipse, later my app will run.. what is the reason for this?

Here is the image

[image: screen snapshot]

Log Messages:

> 12-23 12:33:12.488: E/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 2 12-23
> 12:33:18.518: E/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 17 12-23
> 12:33:19.558: E/BatteryService(59): usbOnlinePath not found 12-23
> 12:33:19.558: E/BatteryService(59): batteryVoltagePath not found 12-23
> 12:33:19.558: E/BatteryService(59): batteryTemperaturePath not found
> 12-23 12:33:19.578: E/SurfaceFlinger(59): Couldn't open
> /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake 12-23
> 12:33:24.268: E/EventHub(59): could not get driver version for
> /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter 12-23 12:33:24.268:
> E/EventHub(59): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not
> a typewriter 12-23 12:33:24.519: E/System(59): Failure starting core
> service 12-23 12:33:24.519: E/System(59): java.lang.SecurityException
> 12-23 12:33:24.519: E/System(59):     at
> android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method) 12-23 12:33:24.519:
> E/System(59):     at
> android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
> 12-23 12:33:24.519: E/System(59):     at
> android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72) 12-23
> 12:33:24.519: E/System(59):   at
> com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184) 12-23
> 12:33:25.609: E/SoundPool(59): error loading
> /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg 12-23 12:33:25.609:
> E/SoundPool(59): error loading
> /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg 12-23 12:33:25.618:
> E/SoundPool(59): error loading
> /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg 12-23 12:33:25.618:
> E/SoundPool(59): error loading
> /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg 12-23 12:33:25.618:
> E/SoundPool(59): error loading
> /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg 12-23 12:33:27.728:
> E/ThrottleService(59): Could not open GPS configuration file
> /etc/gps.conf 12-23 12:33:28.447: E/logwrapper(140): executing
> /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory 12-23 12:33:28.469:
> E/logwrapper(142): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or
> directory 12-23 12:33:28.629: E/logwrapper(145): executing
> /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory 12-23 12:33:32.568:
> E/AndroidRuntime(122): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 12-23 12:33:32.568:
> E/AndroidRuntime(122): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
> activity
> ComponentInfo{com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}:
> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
>
> ## 0x7f030009 12-23 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>
> 12-23 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
> 12-23 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 12-23
> 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
> 12-23 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):    at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 12-23
> 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):  at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 12-23 12:33:32.568:
> E/AndroidRuntime(122):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 12-23
> 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-23
> 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 12-23 12:33:32.568:
> E/AndroidRuntime(122):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> 12-23 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 12-23
> 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):  at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 12-23 12:33:32.568:
> E/AndroidRuntime(122): Caused by:
> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
>
> ## 0x7f030009 12-23 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892) 12-23
>
> 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):  at
> android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1869)
> 12-23 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):    at
> android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731) 12-23
> 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318) 12-23
> 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276) 12-23
> 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):  at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
> 12-23 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):    at
> android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647) 12-23
> 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):  at
> com.android.launcher2.Launcher.onCreate(Launcher.java:236) 12-23
> 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):  at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
> 12-23 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
> 12-23 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122):    ... 11 more 12-23
> 12:33:41.994: E/HierarchicalStateMachine(59): TetherMaster -
> unhandledMessage: msg.what=3

Also once i close and start the emulator my app will not launch at all, for this i need to close eclipse and start again. what is the reason for this?

Comment: its because something in the android launcher code is breaking. If you made changes to it then fix what you broke or revert it. The second option would be to delete the platform that you are using and re-download it.

Comment: what error do you get in your log cat?

Comment: Chech the log. adb logcat at the console should give you the stack trace.

Comment: Its not related to your app at all its launcher app I hope your app is not a modified launcher

Comment: Hey, the logs looks very big. how to past?

Comment: just go to 1st line of code and click, move the cursor to end of lines , hold shift , click last line of logcat message. Press Ctrl + C. Edit you question Press Ctrl + V : )

Comment: Thanks, done please have a look once

Answer (score 1):

Issue is related to emulator, delete the existing one and you just create new virtual emulator properly give adequate memories. that's all..

Answer (score 0):

The error should be:

> 12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 12-23
>   12:33:32.568: E/AndroidRuntime(122): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID

Try to debug the activity Launcher, maybe the error should be in `onCreate()` or in `onResume()`. Otherwise you can try a clean project but I don't think that changes something.

Comment: In addition to this, one more problem i'm facing. If i quit and launch the emulator through application, its not at all launching. Simply in progressbar i will get getting text saying its launching :(... wat to do?

Comment: Hi, its my problem.. i setup emulator properly... the issue is solved thanks